# Expansion of the universe and superluminal speeds - an analogy

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, coordinate-systems, space-expansion

To illustrate, let's imagine the whole universe having a coordinate grid. Essentially a great big mesh grid of interlocking meter sticks.

Now... Einstein's theory of relativity tells us that nothing can move faster than the speed of light. That is; no object could slide along more than 299,792,458 meter sticks per second. Photons in particular, move at exactly this speed limit.

On the other hand, some very distant galaxies moving away from us faster than the speed of light - (they appear to slide along more than 299,792,458 meter sticks per second).
Nothing in the galaxy actually moves faster than light, but as Hubble's Law tells us, it's because expansion of the universe is faster, the further away from an observer (us here on planet Earth, as the case might be), and it's actually the expansion of the universe which causes the apparent superluminal speed.

So my question is only, what's happening to my meter stick grid?

- A. Additional meter sticks are materializing; squeezing their way into existence between the meter sticks already in place; thus elongating the grid and pushing things away from us.
- B. Meter sticks in the far parts of the universe are *stretched*; physically expanded such that nothing passes more than 299,792,458 sticks per second; but it appears so because the far-away sticks are longer.
- C. ???

I believe (A), but maybe I'm off my tilter.

Comment: B is correct, if you have a bunch of sticks next to each other, they will remain the same size due to the internal forces (an ideal meter never stretches), but they will slowly get separated from each other though.

Comment: A faraway sticker will also separate slowly from the one next to it, but it will look as moving fast away from you because you need to add all the new gaps in between.

Comment: Isn't that (A)? There are new gaps opening between the meter sticks - I just say "new meter sticks materialize" as a way of saying our "grid" stays intact.

Comment: I mean, they will not materialize spontaneously, but you can add them into the gaps, as there is new "distance" being  created. If that is what you mean, then yes, the answer is A.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see how that was unclear. I don't mean that the meter sticks are really physical things, like... I know the universe isn't spontaneously creating bars of wood or sheet metal, or whatever. I meant indeed that "new distance" was popping up along the axes.